# How to "merge/group by" rows in excel and add the values located on a different column in excel

Tags: excel, vba

```
ID   Name   Valued
1    John    1.23
2    Eve     2.20
1    John    2.30
3    Adam    4.50
3    Eve     2.00
and so on...
```

And I want the result like this

```
ID   Name    Valued
1   John    3.33    "valued were sum from rows 1 & 2 - because they have the same ID"
2   Eve     2.20
3   Adam    6.50    "valued were sum from 4 & 5 - because they have the same ID whatever the data under the column Name"
```

How can I write this using VBA for Excel?

Comment: 1.23 + 2.30 = 3.53 not 3.33. So what do you want?

Comment: `ID 3` have `Adam` and `Eve` but your result displays only `Adam`, what's the idea behind assigning names.

Comment: What have you tried?  Show the formulas or code you have tried, and where you have run into a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the SUMIF() function in Excel - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b

It does exactly what you need. In your case these are the formulas:

```
=SUMIF(C:C,1)
=SUMIF(C:C,2)
=SUMIF(C:C,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

***Assumption:*** Name occurring first for unique id with multiple names should be displayed in the result.

#### Solution 1: Using VBA

Considering your data is in `Column A-C` following will display result in `Column E-G`

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim dataRng As Range
    Dim dic1 As Variant, dic2 As Variant, arr As Variant
    Dim cnt As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")  'change Sheet1 to your data sheet
    Set dic1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dic2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row    'get last row in Column A
        Set dataRng = .Range("A2:C" & lastRow)              'range of data Column A-C
        arr = dataRng.Value                                 'range to array

        For i = 1 To UBound(arr)                            'loop through each row
            dic1(arr(i, 1)) = dic1(arr(i, 1)) + arr(i, 3)   'add values of unique id
            If dic2.exists(arr(i, 1)) = False Then
                dic2(arr(i, 1)) = arr(i, 2)                 'first name for unique id
            End If
        Next
        .Range("E2").Resize(dic1.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dic1.keys)  'uniques id in Column E
        .Range("G2").Resize(dic1.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dic1.items) 'names in Column E
        .Range("F2").Resize(dic2.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dic2.items) 'sum of values in Column E
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

See image for reference.

[image]

#### Solution 2: Using Formula

To get `Unique ID`, enter following formula in `Cell E2`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$6,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF(E$1:$E1,$A$2:$A$6),0,0),0)),"")
```

In `Cell F2` enter following formula to get first occurring corresponding `Name` for ID

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$6,MATCH(E2,$A$2:$A$6,0))
```

Finally to get `Sum of Values`, enter below formula in `Cell G2`

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$6,E2,$C$2:$C$6)
```

Drag/Copy down all formulas as required and change range as per your data.

[image]